# How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates

Currently I'm running Linux-3.0 and I want to update it to Linux-3.3.1 the latest stable kernel release as mentioned at http://www.kernel.org. Can I update to 3.3.1 in Ubuntu without any risk of crashes? I'm updating my kernel regularly as provided by the Update Manager..Currently I have Linux-**3.0.0.17**..*Can I update?*

NOTE:

The latest kernel version any user is supposed to use in Ubuntu is updated automatically via the Update Manager, so no action is normally required by user regarding kernel upgrades. What the question author is referring to is *mainline kernel*, see:  [Should I upgrade to the "mainline" kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels)

Comment: Related: [Should I upgrade to the “mainline” kernels?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels)

Answer (score 147):

The simplest set of instructions I always used for kernel upgrade / downgrade are by [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/) user by the name of lykwydchykyn (url modified by me for this post):

1. Go here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
2. Download 3 (maybe 4) debs to a folder somewhere:

   ```
   linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_all.deb
   linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
   linux-image-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
   linux-image-extra-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb   # if available
   ```
3. Install the debs with whatever package manager front-end you use (is gdebi still around?), or use these commands:

   ```
   cd /path/to/folder/where/you/put/the/debs
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

**Sources:**

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11391743#post11391743

Comment: for example here you find two versions for each architecture: `lowlatency` and `generic`, which to take? http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/

Comment: No luck. I was coming from the 64-bit Utopic lowlatency kernel (3.16.0-31) in the standard repo. I upgraded to v3.16.7-ckt8 ( linux-image-3.16.7-031607-lowlatency_3.16.7-031607.201503111033_amd64.deb) which is running but still no trackpad. This is for an Acer C710.

Comment: I had touch pad problems.   My default bios was set to advanced mode.  It says in the bios there may be problems using advanced mode without a driver.  However basic mode works well in ubuntu.  Unfortunately, basic mode works terrible in windows!   I hope this helps in the easy way.

Comment: For completeness, in addition to @Bucic's steps -- (4) accept the new grub boot loader (1st option).  This is probably what most people need. In case you would like to see exactly what changes, do a comparison to check, but it'll probably just rewrite your Grub conf file with the new kernel info you want. (5) reboot.  Additionally, this is the much safer route, which will also upgrade your Linux version: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo reboot`.  In either scenario, after rebooting, run `echo $(uname -r)` to confirm that you successfully booted into your new kernel.

Comment: @rubo77 on lowlatency vs generic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126664/why-to-choose-low-latency-kernel-over-generic-or-realtime-ones

Comment: Can I do this in Kubuntu 16.10? I'm on 4.8.0-46-generic and I need 4.10.1 but in Kubuntu it will come with kubuntu 17.04 and backports I guess.

Comment: @Hrvoje yes you can, don't forget to also update the compiler(kmake) if necessary. recompiling kernel mods may also be necessary.

Comment: @Ubuntourist --  did you recompile the kernel modules?

Comment: last edit 2014; content still valid in 2018; +1

Comment: @WilliMentzel: not for me. I tried installing 5.9.12, then [5.9.10](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9.10/) and when booting, I keep getting "[can't find command hwmatch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1840560)", and that the kernel has an invalid signature.

Comment: Be aware that `linux-image-extra-...` meanwhile is called `linux-modules-extra-...`.

Comment: I simply hit this commant: 'sudo reboot' and the kernel in use changed to the most recent version

Comment: I suggest simplifying the 3rd point by using `apt install ./*.deb`. This will allow to remove mention of gdebi, and `apt` handles any potential dependencies. As a side note: it is important that the filename(s) should start with `./`, otherwise `apt` wouldn't resolve that to a local file, and will try to download a remote package with that name instead.

Answer (score 86):

You could always do the following:

```
apt-cache search linux-image
```

Pick the one you want and then do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-your_version_choice linux-headers-your_version_choice linux-modules-extra-your_version_choice
```

Comment: That would not give a *mainline* kernel; rather, it would give an Ubuntu build (of the specified version number).

Comment: Probably better than going with a _mainline_ one though, since it's been massaged for the target OS.

Comment: Worked like a charm in Debian 8.
Thank you!

Comment: This loads up to lightdm for me, but my laptops keyboard and USB ports don't work.

Comment: don't forget to install kernel headers too: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-[version]-generic. [version] should be the same as kernel version

Comment: I just crashed my system with a busy box boot.  I think apt is not doing what it was supposed to do.  It "recommended" other installs, but they did not work from the names suggested.  And I think it did not install the headers a, extras and headers all.  It also recommended me to auto remove on library.  DO NOT TRY THIS.   Find the latest version from the kernal site and then google how to install that version.  Rc6 gave me this link (which will change in due time for you)  http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/03/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-5-rc6-in-linux.html

Comment: This entry should be changed so it also instructs the user to install the linux-image-extra package because without it some things might not work - like an USB keyboard you use for entering the password to decrypt your disk.

Comment: @EliahKagan Now days I've noticed the Ubuntu build of the mainline kernel appears in a day or two. So I think http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ is appropriate one to use.

Answer (score 29):

My answer is, YES you can. The stable release was 3.4, but in this tutorial i use 3.3.1.

**Ubuntu (32-bit) Generic PAE:**

Run the following commands:

```
mkdir kernel\ v3.3.1-precise && cd kernel\ v3.3.1-precise
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-headers-3.3.1-030301-generic-pae_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-headers-3.3.1-030301_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-image-3.3.1-030301-generic-pae_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb 
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot now
```

**Ubuntu (64-bit):**

Run the following commands:

```
mkdir kernel\ v3.3.1-precise && cd kernel\ v3.3.1-precise
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-headers-3.3.1-030301-generic_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-headers-3.3.1-030301_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3.1-precise/linux-image-3.3.1-030301-generic_3.3.1-030301.201204021435_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb 
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot now
```

Enjoy!

Comment: i install the kernel 3.8.5-raring as you said on my Ubuntu 12.04. but now my OS is down and there is no cli or any grub menu. just thinking.

Comment: Good but needs to be updated.  I recommend finding the version and then google how to install it.  Click the pages until you find something like this.  For rc6 I found this http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/03/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-5-rc6-in-linux.html

Answer (score 20):

Contrary to some answers here Ubuntu releases the new kernel within a day or two of the main kernel team. I used to upgrade the hard way like some of the answers here suggest but I found this is an easier way.

## Implications of manually installing Kernels

Manually installing kernels requires extra work.

There are reasons why you want to install the latest mainline kernel:

- A bug in the last Ubuntu LTS kernel update and you can't downgrade
- You have new hardware not supported in the current Ubuntu LTS kernel update stream or HWE updates
- You want a security upgrade or new feature only available in the latest mainline kernel version.

As of January 15, 2018 the latest stable mainline kernel is `4.14.13`. At the time of writing many are interested to install it for protection against Meltdown security hole. If you choose to manually install it you should know:

- Older LTS kernels will not [get updated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763360/does-manual-kernel-update-affect-the-next-regular-automatic-update) until they are greater than  the main menu first option titled **Ubuntu**.
- Manually installed kernels are not removed with the usual `sudo apt auto-remove` command. You need to follow this: [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)
- Monitor developments in the older kernels for when you want to get back on the regular LTS kernel update method. Then delete the manually installed mainline kernel as described in the previous bullet point link.
- After manually removing the newest mainline kernel run `sudo update-grub` and then Ubuntu's latest LTS kernel will be the first option called **Ubuntu** on Grub's main menu.

## Finding the latest kernel

Go to ([kernel.ubuntu.com - Kernel PPA Mainline](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)) and press the <kbd>End</kbd> key:

[image: Mainline kernel 1]

Now click on the link `4.9.8` (or a newer one if available when you read this) and the following appears:

[image: mainline kernel 2]

Note the links with the black airbrush marks. These are the three we will download for ***Ubuntu 16.04 64-Bit*** using ***Intel or AMD*** processors.

## Installing using Terminal

Open a terminal session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and use:

```
cd ~/Downloads # Change to your downloads directory
ll linux*.deb  # Check if any previous downloads still exist
rm linux*.deb  # Use this command if any previous downloads found
```

Now switch back to the download screen above and single-click on all three of the `.deb` kernel downloads. After downloads complete (you'll see status in your browser) switch back to terminal session and use:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
rm linux*.deb
sudo reboot
```

Voila! - you are running the latest kernel when the first option in grub boot menu is selected. Your older kernel versions are still available under grub's **Advanced Options** menu.

After installing the newest kernel a dozen times you will ask the question "*How do I remove older kernel versions?*" and you will find those answers here in ***Ask Ubuntu***.

Comment: You should answer [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149191/linux-latest-stable-compilation-cannot-represent-change-to-vmlinux-gdb-py) saying "Don't complicate your life".

Comment: The layout and logging of the kernel page has changed. It would be great if you could refresh this answer's text and screen cap

Comment: @8bitjunkie I just check version 4.9 kernel and it appears the same. What kernel version were you looking at?

Comment: Hi, @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I was looking at https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9.1

Answer (score 15):

Late but new answer.

I will add some more information in my answer. Now my old kernel was `linux-headers-4.8.0-53`. To find out which kernel you have type `uname -r` in terminal. Now type this command to get list of available kernels.

```
apt-cache search linux-image
```

This will give you a very big output. Now chose one of them that you want to install and install it by following commands(Don't type these commands like this, **replace** the words *kernal_version* with the kernel version which you wish to install)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-kernal_version
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-kernal_version
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-kernal_version
```

Now in my case I choose `linux-image-4.10.0-22-generic` so my command will look like this

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.10.0-22-generic 
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-4.10.0-22-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.10.0-22-generic
```

Now in the end remove old kernel by command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now when I first did it, I Don't know is it my hardware problem or because of removing the old kernel, but my laptop shows me black screen which happens to my laptop [sometimes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922705/black-screen-shows-off-suddenly-after-2-4-hours). Thus I remove it's battery and rebooted and typed the command. Also I don't suffer from my [black screen issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922705/black-screen-shows-off-suddenly-after-2-4-hour) any more.

```
uname -r
```

and it gives me

```
linux-image-4.10.0-22-generic
```

which means kernel is updated.

Comment: Yoour black screen issue may be because you removed the kernel in use. After you install the new kernel, you have to reboot. Then remove old kernel.

Comment: Great answer. Although things have changed a little bit now, I had to change `linux-image-extra` into `linux-modules-extra` for version `4.18.0-22-generic` to make this work.

Answer (score 9):

There is a much simpler way of doing this, and it's the way I use. Simply download the [Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Updater](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater) script and run it from a terminal. It will download the .deb's for you, install the new kernel, and optionally remove the old one (not recommended) then optionally reboot.

Example output (copied from my terminal):

```
evilsupahfly@the-black-beast:~$ sudo KernelUpdateChecker -no-rc -r utopic
Run this command to install the new kernel
/tmp/kernel-update
root@the-black-beast:~# /tmp/kernel-update
Config Notes:
Rejecting Release Candidates
Accepting Latest Kernel
Accepting kernels compiled for utopic
Accepting kernels with a version higher than 3.15.0-031500-lowlatency

Information:
Origin: 
    http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15.1-utopic
Kernel Version:
    3.15.1-031501
Release Date:
    2014/06/16 @ 18:41 (YYYY/MM/DD @ HH:MM)

Care to look at the change log? (y=Yes, n=No) (n)

(download output skipped)    

Greetings root
    I (the-black-beast) am now self aware and a sentient being, have a nice day.
    Oh and by the way SKYNET is now active.

Installing Linux 3.15.1-031501:

(installer output skipped)

The New Kernel looks to have been installed

WARNING: If the new kernel does not boot you may regret saying yes here.
Would you like to remove the current one? (y=Yes, n=No) (n): n

Are you ready to Reboot? (y=Yes, n=No) (n): n
```

Almost entirely automated, and completely problem free.

Comment: It was fine in 2014 when I posted the comment originally, however, since then, I've found it easier just to go with the answer @Bucic gave earlier - download the .debs to a folder (`/home/evilsupahfly/Downloads/Kernels/X.XX-something/` in my case) and just do `cd {.deb location}` then `dpkg -i *.deb` in the terminal. No messing with PHP or SkyNet.

Answer (score 7):

Run the following Terminal commands to install a new [Ubuntu mainline kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-bs4 python-apt
cd /tmp
rm -rf medigeek-kmp*
wget https://github.com/medigeek/kmp-downloader/tarball/master -O kmpd.tar.gz
tar xzf kmpd.tar.gz
cd medigeek-*
python kmpd.py -d
```

The script is hosted at [Github](https://github.com/medigeek/kmp-downloader/). Just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of a number if you get stuck on a certain question in the Python script.

Comment: I'm the author of that script. I've just fixed it. Please file bug reports, most of the time programmers don't know bugs exist until someone files a report. :)

Comment: What is the advantage of your script from just doing the install of the `deb` package like described by the best answer here?

Comment: I was just thinking of this type of tool since I crashed because apt did not install dependencies for me.  You would think that apt was all about dependencies.  Wrong.  A script can be updated for the latest release or search for one and let the user choose.  All that said, if I get my system up again, I will go direct since I found the terminal commands for rc6

Comment: @SavvasRadevic `ImportError: No module named apt_pkg`

Comment: @Yahya try installing python-apt `apt install python-apt`

Comment: @SavvasRadevic I already did, but just reporting as per your request.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a script and always will be up to date.

[ukupgrade: Ubuntu Kernel Upgrade](https://github.com/muhasturk/ukupgrade)

- Open your favorite terminal and run the follwing commands
- Give executable permission to file

  `chmod +x ./ukupgrade`
- Call the script

  `./ukupgrade`

Comment: this was the best.

Comment: keeps installing the low latency version when asking for generic~

Comment: I didn't know about this tool so I also wrote a similar tool, which also supports selecting the generic/low latency flavor. You can find it here: https://github.com/cristim/kernel-update

Comment: At this time, this script is broken and WON'T work.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to go through the hassle to manually upgrade the kernel you can try UUKU. Works fine even on Ubuntu derivatives like elementory,  mint.

I used it to fix my WiFi issue as sometimes some new hardware won't be detected by old kernel. 
Other  than hardware driver update I don't find the need to upgrade kernel.
New kernels do have security and slight performance upgrade but also have tendency to break things like your VM.

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
ukuu-gtk
```

SOURCE:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/upgrade-kernel-ukuu-ubuntu/

http://www.teejeetech.in/2016/07/ukuu-v167.html?m=1

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to try customized and optimized builds, such as this i3/i5/i7 optimized 3.2.1 kernel for Ubuntu:

[DuoPetalFlower, My Experiments with Linux - 3.2.1 kernel](http://duopetalflower.blogspot.com/2012/01/ready-3-2-1-go.html)

He also has Intel atom optimized builds which can work quite well if you're trying to squeeze every last ounce of performance out of a netbook.

There are other kernels like [Liquorix](http://liquorix.net/) that claim to be better optimized for desktop performance.

Though not recommended by some, you can often run [official kernels](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=M;O=D) from later versions of Ubuntu without issues. I'm currently running the 3.3.3 precise kernel on oneiric and my machine works better than ever. Performance & battery life increased, while temperatures dropped a few degrees. My issue of a black screen when resuming from standby has also disappeared. Though I personally haven't had issues from using newer kernels, you will find some people who are strongly opposed to doing this.

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen, Ubuntu does provide versions of the Linux kernel, but not always as fast as they are released upstream, you can always compile the 3.3.1 kernel yourself, but that may be more effort than you were looking for. If not, search around and I'm sure you'll find a tutorial you can follow such as [this one](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/03/how-to-install-linux-33-kernel-in.html). (note that I haven't checked that one thoroughly so be wary as kernels are dangerous beasts)

Answer (score 2):

I created this script `kernel-upgrade.sh` that downloads and installs a selected kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline:

```sh
TMP=/var/tmp/kernel
mkdir -p "$TMP" && cd "$TMP"
rm -f "$TMP"/*
F=v4.16-rc6
V=4.16.0-041600rc6
R=$(wget -qO - "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/$F/0005-debian-changelog.patch" | sed -ne '/^+linux/{s/.*\.\([0-9]\+\)).*/\1/p;q}')
B="$V.$R"
URL=http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline
set -x
wget "$URL/$F/linux-headers-$V-generic_${B}_amd64.deb" \
    "$URL/$F/linux-headers-${V}_${B}_all.deb" \
    "$URL/$F/linux-image-$V-generic_${B}_amd64.deb"
sudo dpkg -i "linux-headers-$V-generic_${B}_amd64.deb" \
    "linux-headers-${V}_${B}_all.deb linux-image-$V-generic_${B}_amd64.deb"
# now enter: sudo reboot now
```

In case Ubuntu doesn't start with the new kernel, you can select "advanced settings" in your grub menu and select to start the last running kernel there.

---

*Note:* since 4.15-rc7 the kernel has the KPTI fix against **meltdown attacks** and since 4.15.1 for "Spectre Variant 2, Mitigation 2"
 (check with http://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker/)

Comment: I'm having some difficulty running this script. I may be doing something wrong, so here are my steps: 1. Disabled secure boot in BIOS, 2. saved the script to `kernel-upgrade.sh`, and `chmod 777 kernel-upgrade.sh`. I then ran it as `sudo ./kernel-upgrade.sh`.
I then get the errors: `rm: cannot remove '/var/tmp/kernel/*': No such file or directory`; then `++ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16...`<truncating url>`
Connecting to kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)|91.189.94.216|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found`
The 404 happens 3x

Comment: the first warning by `rm` could be ignored (I added `rm -f` now). the rest is not clear, what is the problem. truncating url here is not helping, solving the problem. can you post the output in https://pastebin.com/, so we can see what the resulting url would be?

Comment: sure, pasted over here  https://pastebin.com/KcdVdKQr

Comment: also if it matters, I am running ubuntu 17.10

Comment: It said this is the wrong path: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16-rc6/linux-headers-4.16.0-041600rc6-generic_4.16.0-041600rc6._amd64.deb check this for the right path: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16-rc6/

Comment: I think the problem may be that the script is adding a sequence of numbers twice? It tries to get `linux-headers-4.16.0-041600rc6-generic_4.16.0-041600rc6.201803182230201803182230_amd64.deb` and it 404s. Though on the site I can see a url for `linux-headers-4.16.0-041600rc6-generic_4.16.0-041600rc6.201803182230_amd64.deb`. The constructed url in the script is the same as this except it repeats `201803182230` twice

Comment: feel free to edit this script so it works for you. SO has an edit function (if you have enough reputation)

Comment: cool, with a quick fix to the wget lines it works like a charm! ty!

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers satisfied my problem of manually update the kernel to the latest stable version. (My current laptop is very sensitive to RCs, Dell XPS 9365).

I created a shell script that searches for more recent kernel versions and shows them as options to be installed. You can give it a try, it's on [github](https://github.com/pdelteil/shellscripts/blob/master/installKernel.sh), please be sure to read the README.

Comment: Github repo: 404 not found.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub updated!

Answer (score 2):

to install the latest kernel
install Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa

$ sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

disable access control with the following command:

```
$ sudo xhost +
```

then install with ukuu

```
$ sudo ukuu

$ sudo ukuu --install-latest
```

then run for secure

```
$ sudo xhost -
```

and reboot

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: if you want to see a list of all kernel versions use 'sudo ukuu --list'.

Comment: if you want to see other options of ukuu type 'ukuu --help'

Comment: Shouldn't you do `sudo xhost -` after you are done? (compare: https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu/issues/25#issuecomment-341501666)

Comment: @student, yes, thank you! I added it to the list of steps

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found a really easy commandline interface for upgrading which is hassle free, its a single bash script called [ubuntu-mainline-kernel](https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh)
Install:

```
apt install wget
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
chmod +x ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
sudo mv ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

then for help

```
ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -h
```

or just checkout the README.md on the first link. Easy and doesn't install extra junk

Answer (score 1):

There is a fork of UKUU, it is named Mainline, it is located at [Github](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline).
And installable [from PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecappelikan/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=) as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mainline
```

And then it will be available as `mainline` (CLI) and `mainline-gtk` (GUI).

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Kernel Version
`$ uname -sr`

Download Kernel v5 for 32 bit

```
$ wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0/linux-headers-5.0.0-050000-generic_5.0.0-050000.201903032031_i386.deb
$ wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0/linux-image-5.0.0-050000-generic_5.0.0-050000.201903032031_i386.deb
$ wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0/linux-modules-5.0.0-050000-generic_5.0.0-050000.201903032031_i386.deb`
```

Download Kernel v5 for 64 bit

```
$ wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0/linux-headers-5.0.0-050000-generic_5.0.0-050000.201903032031_amd64.deb
$ wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0/linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-050000-generic_5.0.0-050000.201903032031_amd64.deb
$ wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0/linux-modules-5.0.0-050000-generic_5.0.0-050000.201903032031_amd64.deb`
```

Install it

`$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Then Reboot

`sudo reboot`